# Using aggregate on data sorted by frequency

Tags: r, sorting, dataframe, aggregate

By using this R command on my data frame `clean_data` I can get the top 100 most common diagnosis.

```
head(sort(table(clean_data$Diagnosis),decreasing = TRUE),n = 100)
```

I can get the mean "Claimed Amount" for each diagnosis like so:

```
aggregate(clean_data$Claimed.Amount,list(clean_data$Diagnosis),mean)
```

But they come out sorted in alphabetical order on the Diagnosis field.

How could I combine the two approaches to get an aggregate mean list grouped by Diagnosis but sorted by the most common ones at the top. Say only the top 100 diagnosis by frequency.

Comment: Sounds like a common sorting of a data.frame by column. What have you tried?

Comment: @RomanLuštrik If I store the `aggregate` command's output in a temp data frame I lost out on the count info generated by the `table` command. How do I sort the first using the info from the second?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Reformatting your question**

You should really learn to ask you question in a simple, reproducible way. For example, I think this is an equivalent description of your problem:

```
set.seed(0)  ## set random seed for reproducibility
## some toy data, open access to everyone to play with
## use simply variable name `x`, `y`, `foo`, not those from special context
foo <- data.frame(y = runif(100),
                  x = sample(letters[1:4], 100, replace = TRUE))
## result from table:
sort(table(foo$x), decreasing = TRUE)

 # c  b  a  d 
 # 33 25 21 21 

## your call to aggregation
aggregate(y ~ x, foo, mean)

## the undesired output you see
  x         y
1 a 0.5537179
2 b 0.5263702
3 c 0.4358863
4 d 0.6145186
```

And this is your desired output:

```
  x         y
1 c 0.4358863
2 b 0.5263702
3 a 0.5537179
4 d 0.6145186
```

If you ask your question in above way, it is easier for people to understand and help. Such transformation is an important skill.

**One possible solution**

You can simply try this:

```
## store the result of table() and aggregate()
count <- sort(table(foo$x), decreasing = TRUE)
oo <- aggregate(y ~ x, foo, mean)
## reordering
oo <- oo[match(names(count), oo$x), ]
rownames(oo) <- 1:length(count)

  x         y
1 c 0.4358863
2 b 0.5263702
3 a 0.5537179
4 d 0.6145186
```

If you want to append `count` to `oo`, do:

```
oo$count <- as.integer(count)
oo

  x         y count
1 c 0.4358863    33
2 b 0.5263702    25
3 a 0.5537179    21
4 d 0.6145186    21
```

Comment: Thanks! This was the idiom I was missing. `[match(oo$x, names(count)), ]` I will try to post as you suggested. Sometimes the risk in producing a toy example is the introduction of a second inadvertent error so I had avoided that.

Comment: Hmmm....doesn't seem to work for my case. Not sure what I'm doing wrong. I tried your simplified example and that works fine.

Comment: Would it matter that my `aggregate` call is slightly different than yours? `aggregate(clean_data[,c("Claimed.Amount","Paid.Amount")],list(clean_data$Diagnosis),mean)` i.e. I'm not using the formula notation

Comment: Yes, three columns. Group.1, Claimed.Amount & Paid.Amount. No error message but it just produces the rows in a strange order. Not yet seeing the pattern about the order it produces. Basically the order of `Diagnosis` I am getting in oo is not the same as I can see within `counts`.

Comment: Thanks for your patience helping me with this debug! `colnames(foo)` is [1] "Group.1"        "Claimed.Amount" "Paid.Amount"  . `nrow(foo)` gives  [1] 619. `length(count)` gives [1] 619

Comment: `count <- sort(table(clean_data$Diagnosis), decreasing = TRUE)
`  followed by  `oo<-aggregate(clean_data[,c("Claimed.Amount","Paid.Amount")],list(clean_data$Diagnosis),mean)` and finally `oo_new <- oo[match(oo$Group.1, names(count)), ]`

Comment: I think I may have figured it out. Shouldn't the call to match be the other way around? i.e. `oo[match(names(count), oo$Group.1), ]`

Comment: It's a fascinating case of how you could get the toy example right by serendipity. Just try your example with `letter[1:5]` and then it fails. Then try it with `oo[match(names(count),oo$x), ]` and it works. I think we were just unlucky that for the test case even the wrong idiom gave the right answer! :)

Comment: No need to be embarrassed at all. If you hadn't been around to bounce my debug ideas at I'd have given up long ago. :p Besides, the crucial learning point was me was this creative use of the match() function. After that it was just some tiresome debugging. So thanks for all the help!!!